# How to plot wind vectors in a vertical cross section in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have WRF model output data for u wind (x-component), v wind (y-component), and w wind (z-component). The data has dimensions of lon*lat*levels*time. Now I want to plot the meridional-vertical circulation vector in the latitude vs altitude (or pressure) cross-section.  Since 'quiver' needs two vectors and the cross-section is along the latitudes, I took v and w wind components to plot the meridional-vertical circulation vector. I took mean over lon and time dimension. So, final matrix of v and w wind components is the size of lat*levels. Now, when I wanted to plot using 'quiver(LAT,LEVELS,V,W)', I am getting absurd vectors which doesn't make sense. So, Can anyone please guide me to solve this problem? That will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.
With regards,
Ankan